# Iterate through a modelview map

Tags: javascript

I use Spring MVC in my project. In my controller, I add a map of values in to the modelview.

Now I need to get the value "map" for key "myMap" and retrieve the all key and its respective value inside the "map" in JavaScript.

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you add more info of what you have done in your question?

Comment: This is my small higlighted method . I hope this will help you to understand.
public ModelAndView getX(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,HttpSession session) {
ModelAndView  modelView = new ModelAndView("xyz");
Map map = new HashMap();map.put("key1", "value1");map.put("key2", "value2");
map.put("key3", "value3");
modelView .addObject("myMap", map); return modelView;
}
xyz.jsp : 
$(function() {var myMap = $('#myMap');
for (var key in myMap ) {if (myMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       alert(key + " -> " + myMap [key]);}}}
I want those map key and value here in jsp